# LostFocus event of a window isn't firing

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, window, focus

I have a window:

```
<Window ...
    LostFocus="SpecialLettersLayout_OnLostFocus">

    ....    

</Window>
```

In this window I have a canvas, and in it I have a Path object which has a non-rectangular form.

In this window I call the LostFocus event. In the .xaml.cs file for that window, I define the SpecialLettersLayout_OnLostFocus event:

```
private void SpecialLettersLayout_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

In my application I have a window and when I click on a button, this window is opened. This window is smaller than the background window, so that means that the background window is still visible.

When I click on the background window I want to hide the small window, because its focus is lost. However, the SpecialLettersLayout_OnLostFocus event isn't hit. Why is that happening?

Comment: How do you Call the `LostEvent`? It's not clear at all what you are asking here.

Comment: @NovitchiS The code shows how do I call it: in the Window tag I have     LostFocus="SpecialLettersLayout_OnLostFocus">

Answer (score 3):

The `LostFocus` event is used for logical focus. What you need here is a physical focus which has another name called `LostKeyboardFocus`.

Logical focus involves using of `FocusManager`. I'm not really sure when `LostFocus` is triggered but it's not the traditional `LostFocus` you thought. Instead we have to use `LostKeyboardFocus`. Also you may have to change your handler to suit the `LostKeyboardFocus` event. The handler type is `KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler`.

Comment: For me the `LostKeyboardFocus` event fired even when selecting something inside the `window`, this wasn't what I wanted and so to fix this I simply check `this.IsActive` in that method and returned if it was true: Because when it is true the window as a whole still has focus.

Comment: LostKeyboardFocus is not the correct event either; as the OP mentioned in their reply, 'Deactivated' is the event that's fired on loss of window-system focus. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.deactivated?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 2):

In the end what helped me was the Deactivated event, which didn't work in combination with ShowDialog(), so I used it with Show() instead.